# CSS Absolute Positioning. IE9/8 vs FF/Chrome/IE7

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioning problem.  My site works well in FF/Chrome/IE7.  In IE9/8 it's not doing what I think it should.

I have two forms on my page.  One is at the bottom outside of the main page structure (just how I had to do it using asp.net webforms and braintree...)

I then have some CSS to put the form back at the top of the page so it looks like it's inline.

```
#NewPaymentForm
{
    position:absolute;
    top:160px;
    left:40px;
}
```

This works as expected in FF/Chrome/IE7. In IE9/8 it's just appended to the bottom of my page.  It looks like it's relative to another div.

I wouldn't mind doing a conditional css statement for this, but I can't get any statement that will bring the form to the top of the page.

The page is [www.trainerroad.com/sign-up-payment](http://www.trainerroad.com/sign-up-payment).  You can see what I'm talking about there.

If anyone can give me some CSS to move the form to the top of the page in IE9/8 and explain why it works that would be awesome.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id` attributes on the page. For instance `"containerMain"`. That breaks your CSS code...

Comment: That only happens in IE, not in Chrome.  Weird...

Comment: When you have invalid HTML code, different browsers will parse it differently, so you get different results. That's why you want your HTML code to be valid.

Comment: FF and Chrome will show what you wrote. IE makes  things up as it goes along. You can never trust IE to do anything right or consistently between versions.

Answer (score 1):

Nate, in your answer, you're using JavaScript browser detection to fix your problem. I think there are better ways to target specific browsers.

One approach is using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
... link IE 6 specific stylesheet or a script...
<![endif]-->
```

This approach will also make your page forward-compatible, so that future versions of IE can render it without needing all the IE6 (and lower) styles.

Another way (and a better approach in my opinion) is the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) approach. You start off your HTML page with this...

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!-- misteroneill.com/improved-internet-explorer-targeting-through-body-classes/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie ie8 lte9 lte8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="no-js ie ie9 lte9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]>
<!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
...
```

... and then you can do like...

```
.ie9 #NewPaymentForm, .ie8 #NewPaymentForm {
    top: 160px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's the code that doesn't work as stated in my original question.  I would use conditional comments but I don't know what the correct CSS is.

Comment: IE 8 and IE 9 both have a web inspector, like Firebug and Chrome's web inspector. You should open it up and play with the values until it looks right in that browser. Then use those values in your conditional stylesheet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it with some jquery:

```
    var browser = $.browser.version;
    if(browser == "9.0" || browser == "8.0")
    {
        $("#NewPaymentForm").offset({ top: 160, left: 150 });
    }
```